# Uneven bit number in a C File

Tags: c, file

I am doing exam prep and not sure what the following question means by considering the situation where the file ends at an uneven bit number. Thanks

Write a C abstract data type(ADT) of a file that allows information to be written to the file one bit at a time.Your ADT should support operations to open a new file, write a bit to the file, and close the file. Note that you will need to use normal C file features within your ADT. You also need to consider the situation where the file ends at an uneven bit number.

Comment: It's very oddly formulated, did you translate it from some other language? The problem is not usually with whether the number of bits is odd or even, it's if the number of bits make up a whole number of *bytes* or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal C facilities allow you to write only full bytes of data. You can create a file say, 4-bytes long, containing 16 bits of data, or 5-bytes long, containing 24 bits of data. You can't write 20 bits to a file because you have no means of saving half a byte.

In order to do what you want you need to create some kind of wrapper: say, first byte contain the number of bits which are "meaningful" in the last byte. That way you write first byte of "4" (4 bits on top of the "even" 16), and then 5 bytes of data, where the last byte contains whatever junk on 4 youngest bits.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have a number of bits which is not a multiple of `8`.

The reason why this might be problematic is because the smallest unit that can be written to a file is a byte, which is 8 bits.

That implies that your new file format will have to encode some kind of metadata to track exactly how many bits to reinterpret when reading from the file.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to various encrypting schemes that have a *bit* rather than a byte (8-bit) length.

Simple treat an extra last byte appended to the file as a count of the number of *padding* bits in the previous byte.  The extra byte would have the value 0 to 7 (or 0 to `CHAR_BIT`-1)